# Is there way to rename user role name without plugin?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

Is there anyway to rename a user role name via hook, instead of using plugin?

#### Edit

For example, `administrator` » `owner`

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: rename user role name, that's it.
for example, administrator -> owner

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
function change_role_name() {
    global $wp_roles;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_roles ) )
        $wp_roles = new WP_Roles();

    //You can list all currently available roles like this...
    //$roles = $wp_roles->get_names();
    //print_r($roles);

    //You can replace "administrator" with any other role "editor", "author", "contributor" or "subscriber"...
    $wp_roles->roles['administrator']['name'] = 'Owner';
    $wp_roles->role_names['administrator'] = 'Owner';           
}
add_action('init', 'change_role_name');
```

http://www.garyc40.com/2010/04/ultimate-guide-to-roles-and-capabilities/

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Regardless of what I do, then it's still called 'Subscribers' in the backend creation process. It looks like that `$wp_roles` now has a `[role_objects]` part of it's array.

Comment: This did something very strange. It only affected the first letter ("Odministrator")!

Comment: This solution will not update the db entry. You are updating the name for the current instance, if this action does not fire, it can mess up your logic.  There is no method in Wp_Role to save. Best way is to `$roles = get_option('user_roles'); $roles['administrator']['name'] = "Owner"; update_option('user_roles', $roles); ` that snipped will only need to be ran once.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using WP version 4.7+ you may accomplish this using the `wp_roles_init` action like so:

```php
add_action( 'wp_roles_init', static function ( \WP_Roles $roles ) {
    $roles->roles['administrator']['name'] = 'Owner';
    $roles->role_names['administrator'] = 'Owner';
} );
```

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Tip: This code works inside a plugin or mu-plugin. It does not work inside a child-theme, as the child theme is loaded too late for the `wp_roles_init` hook.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there are many ways to achieve that:

With **pure php and mysql** you can edit the serialized entry in the db. Indeed, Wordpress stores the serialized array of roles in `wp_options` table.

So:

1. Fetch the serialized array:
   `SELECT option_value as serialized_string FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wp_user_roles';`
2. Unserialize the string – php: `$rolesArray = unserialize($serialized_string)`
3. Change the role name – php: `$rolesArray['role_key']['name'] = "New name"`
4. Serialize back the array – php: `echo serialize($rolesArray)`
5. Replace the db `option_value` content with output from the previous point

If you feel confident with Wordpress, you can even use the [embedded Wordpress REPL in wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) to fetch the stored value with `get_option('wp_user_roles')` and then use `update_option` to update it.

**And (always) remember to backup the db before options manipulation ;)**

---

#### Otherwise, if you don’t care about role_key value…

…it’s very easy to achieve that with [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/):

1. duplicate the existing role – `$ wp role create new_role 'New Role' --clone=old_role`
2. delete the old one – `$ wp role delete old_role`
3. then associate new_role to the user(s).
4. *eventually repeat step 1 and 2 until old_role = new_role*

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to just add a user role using `add_role`, that way you can name it whatever you want and add whatever capabilities you want.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role

Comment: Tried to avoid this, but I guess it's the cleanest way to do without plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom localization file. Get this file: http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/pot/trunk/wordpress.pot and edit using  PoEdit tool (for example). In next step save localization file as en_GB.mo (or other) and edit wp-config file:

define ("WPLANG", "en_GB");

Comment: Already tried this method, but some pull down menus were not translated.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it directly in your DB, and it will be edited permanently for your website. Here is where WP keeps user roles

```
SELECT * from blog_options WHERE option_name = 'blog_user_roles'
```